# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

Getting the below error while loading `Null` value to database in spark . `Datatype` of the target table is `smallint`

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for null
```

code :

```
val hivedata = spark.sql(s"""select 1 as column1 , B a column2 , NULL as column3 from table""")

hivedata .write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url = con, table = targettable, Pconnectionropertiess)
```

can anyone please help me

Answer (score 9):

`cast(NULL as smallint)` you have to do... this will convert null to `short` type as showed in below schema.

```
val df1 =spark.sql(
     " select 1 as column1 , 2 column2 , cast(NULL as smallint) as column3 from table  ")
  df1.show
df1.printSchema()
```

Result :

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|      2|   null|
+-------+-------+-------+

root
 |-- column1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- column2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- column3: short (nullable = true)
```

**other wise your way** it will be nulltype not small int type..

```
val df1 =spark.sql(" select 1 as column1 , 2 column2 ,  NULL   as column3 from table  ")
  df1.show
df1.printSchema()
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|      2|   null|
+-------+-------+-------+

root
 |-- column1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- column2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- column3: null (nullable = true)
```

Thats the reason you are getting the exception.